# how can I programmatically remove the image from a folder "Drawable"?

Tags: android, drawable

I have a source code that loads images into the folder "Drawable"

```
private void drawable_from_url(String url, String src_name) throws java.net.MalformedURLException, java.io.IOException {
    android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromStream(((java.io.InputStream)new java.net.URL(url).getContent()), src_name);
}
```

**but how can I remove them?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not writing to the "res/drawable" folder. You are creating a new android.graphics.drawable.Drawable object from the stream.
Any resource file is "hard-coded" on the apk and you can not touch them, except to load them using theirs ids.